# How do I Bind data to a nested DevExpress GridView control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm new to DevExpress controls and am having issues with a master-detail gridview.

I'm using DXperience-11.2.

I can easily bind an object to the parent GridView by doing the following:

```
var myObject = myObject.Retrieve(id);

parentGridView.DataSource = myObject;
parentGridView.DataBind();
```

I'm having difficulty binding to the nested child GridView. I'm using the following code (as I've used many times before with nested asp:Repeaters) but the resulting var childGrid object is always null.

```
var childGrid = (ASPxGridView)parentGridView.FindControl("childGridView");

var myObject2 = myObject2.Retrieve(id);

childGrid.DataSource = myObject2;
childGrid .DataBind();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Kris

Comment: try FindByName("parentGridViewName").FindControl("childGridViewName")

Comment: Hi Brian Thanks for you quick response. I dont seem to have a 'FindByName' method...

Comment: are you creating an instance of the childGridView dynamically or is it on the webpage?   try var childGrid= new ASPxGridView;  childGrid.FindControl("childGridView")   then bind your data to childGrid.

Comment: Can you share your markup (at least the part relevant to the question)?

Comment: The child gridview in on the web page. I've tried your sugestion but it diesnt work because it creates another gridview in memory not the one im trying to bind too. Kris

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thanks for the suggestions posted but I managed to come up with the solution.

I added the following event to the parent gridview...

```
OnBeforePerformDataSelect="detailGrid_DataSelect"
```

This event fires when you click on a row in the parent gridview. The parent gridview row expands and the event fires.

Then in my code behind I did the following code...

```
    protected void detailGrid_DataSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myObject2 = myObject2.Retrieve(id);

        ASPxGridView grid = (sender as ASPxGridView);
        grid.DataSource = myObject2;
    }
```

To begin I retrieved the object I wanted to bind to the nested/child GridView. Then cast the object sender to an ASPxGridView Object and bind the data object I retrieved.

I was going wrong because I trying to find the nested GridView control using the .FindControl method in this event when really the object sender is the nested GridView object.

Hope this helps anyone who was in the same pickle as me!

Kris